# windbg - automatically continue when child process created and .childdbg 1 enabled

Tags: windbg

I'm using a startup script for windbg, and would like to debug child processes (.childdbg 1).  However, once I enable it, i find that windbg automatically breaks when the child process is created.  I'm not sure why this is occurring, but here's the script I'm using:

```
sxe -c ".echo ********** CLR 1st Chance Exception **********;!pe -nested;.echo ----------- CLRStack ----------;!clrstack;g" clr
sxe -c ".echo Child Process Created;g" cpr
sxe -c ".echo Child Process Exited;g" epr
.load psscor2.dll
.childdbg 1
```

I'm invoking this via the following command:

```
windbg.exe -Q -c "$<c:\path\startup.ini" Foo.exe
```

Lastly, here's the output in windbg:

```
(1d14.191c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=0022f86c edx=778670b4 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=778c04f6 esp=0022f888 ebp=0022f8b4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
778c04f6 cc              int     3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `sxi ibp` to ignore initial breakpoint events
You may also want to ignore process exit `sxi epr`

Comment: Thank you. Looks like alt-9 is how I navigate between the proccesses as well.

Comment: One more question - my parent app spawns two children. I see the first one is visible to windbg, but the 2nd is not listed in 'processes and threads'.  However, Process explorer shows both processes as children of the parent. Is something else needed for more than one child?

Comment: You can also use the `|` command to list/select a processes.  You should see all child processes.  Unless they already existed.

Comment: Thanks again. Oddly, I now see it in alt-9 as well.