# How to get memory dump on specific Exception after application pool recycle

Tags: asp.net, windbg, memory-dump, debugdiag

After our app pool recycles our WCF services throw FileLoadException on access. Recycling of app pool helps. Sometimes the error goes away without recycling. I asked the question
I asked first question about it here: [FileLoadException when accessing WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21383463/fileloadexception-when-accessing-wcf-service)

As we have no other ideas how to analyze this problem we would like to get memory dump with that Exception in it.

But I don't know how to configure adplus or debugdiag to attach automatically to that new process (after recycling) and generate crash dump on specific exception. Is that even possible?

Comment: Independent on how the dump is created, don't forget to copy all SOS.dll and mscordacwks.dll from the system in order to be able to analyze the dump.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Procdump`](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx) to make the full memory dump on the first chance exception:

```
procdump -ma -e 1 -f FileLoadException w3wp.exe
```

But unfortunately you will probably have to attach it manually as I do not know any out-of-the-box solution. We are sometimes using PowerShell scripts for such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Use WinDbg, attach it and add an event filter via the menu 'Debug>Event Filters...'
Click 'Add..' and the error code should be `0x80131621` according to the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileloadexception(v=vs.110).aspx) but it could be different which could be a problem and then enter `gc`.
Otherwise I expect WinDbg to break when the exception occurs and you can then do a dump:

```
.dump /ma c:\dumps\mycrash.dmp
```

You may have looked at the following pages regarding how to debug this issue:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx and http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2007/12/we-were-crashin.html, [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295626/troubleshooting-system-io-fileloadexception)

Comment: but attach to what? I need to get dump of new process that is created after app pool recycle.

Comment: Attach to the host service and you need to enable debugging of child processes using `.childdbg 1` there is a related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340336/windbg-automatically-continue-when-child-process-created-and-childdbg-1-enabl)

Comment: @Peri I haven't tried with .net though so not sure if this will 100% work a [2005 post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/08/16/debug-child-process.aspx) said this was not possible but it may be different in 2014